# Can not find .gitconfig in user directory

Tags: windows, git, home-directory

I opened the CMD and go to my user folder. Inside is the .gitconfig file.

When I do `git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128`

it says that the file/folder .gitconfig is not found!

Why this?

Answer (score 1):

That weird.
If your configuration file really doesn't exist, then executing `git config --global --list` should give you the location is it expected to be.
You should check if permissions to that directory are sufficient for git to write to that file...

You can also execute `git config --global --edit` to edit the file directly.

If you want to change your config file path, you can do so by creating an environment variable called `home`, and pointing it to your desired location.

See [Git Config Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for additional information